# Get the node IP of a particular Kubernetes service through Java

Tags: java, kubernetes

I have a scenario where I have a Kubernetes cluster of three nodes. Now there is a service(say `testService`) running on the cluster(any one of the three nodes). I would like to know if there is any way through which I can get the IP of the node on which the service is running by using the kubernetes API.

I looked through the documentation and all I could find was APIs to get the status/names of the services.

**Edit**: There is a UI page which targets the service. The problem is that on a new deployment the service can be scheduled on either of the three nodes.

Comment: Why do you need the IP of the node? Are you trying to connect to the service?

Comment: Yes, there is a webpage which targets the particular service.

Comment: Assuming you've properly exposed it as a service, you should have `FOO_SERVICE_HOST` and `FOO_SERVICE_PORT` in the environment. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-environment-variables/

Comment: @kichik I have exposed the service through loadBalancer and I'm trying to access it from outside the cluster through a webpage.

Comment: Then `kubectl describe services my-new-service` should give you the information you need.

Comment: @kichik yes I very well know that. But I wanted to get it through java code so as to update the url(for targeting the service)  dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it with the [Kubernetes Java API](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java).

You can basically get it with a *describe service*  call and picking up the endpoints of your service. An example endpoint output would look like something this:

```
192.168.1.1:8888,192.168.2.2:8888
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually my specific question was directed towards how to use the API to achieve the said goal. But nevermind, I got it working by using the fabric8 platform.